# Using CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING in a CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, substring, case, charindex

I need to evaluate a field with a CASE statement.  The field name is Commodity and is a varchar(255).  The values differ and I need to extract a specific portion from it after a specific character.  The character is a '>'. I was able to come up with the value I want returned after the > by using the following code:

```
SUBSTRING(Commodity, CHARINDEX('>', Commodity) + 2, LEN(Commodity))
```

I am however unsure of how to work this into my CASE statement.  I need to test for Is Null and then just assign it a value of 'No Commodity'.  Then I need to test for the presence of a > and then implement the code above to return the value.  Then I need to test for when there is no > but it is not null and just return the value of the Commodity field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to have these three conditions in `when` clauses. You can use `charindex` to make sure the `>` character exists in the string:

```
CASE 
WHEN commodity IS NULL THEN 'No Comodity'
WHEN CHARINDEX('>', Commodity) > 0 THEN 
     SUBSTRING(commodity, CHARINDEX('>', commodity) + 2, LEN(commodity))
ELSE comodity
END
```